# Is it possible to save Angular form data back to the scope so that it persists between refreshes on a single non-hosted HTML file?

Tags: angularjs

I have a single local HTML file (not web hosted, no backends, etc) that I use as a quick'n'dirty dashboard at work. All CSS styles and JS scripts are embedded rather than linked separate files.

I've implemented a simple Angular-based knowledgebase which basically lists all items in a scope I have in the HTML file.

I have some test code that allows me to add and remove entries from the scope (using .push and .splice), but the data in the HTML file doesn't change so when I hit refresh on the browser the entries return to what is 'hardcoded' in the HTML file.

**My question:** is there a way I can get this data added/removed from the scope to physically write back to the HTML file so that it persists between refreshes?

Comment: Instead of writing to the file, just use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: I did consider this, but there is a risk that my organisation will occasionally force browser cache cleardowns ... will my localStorage persist if this happens?

Comment: I guess that depends on the browser. You could also have a look at a pretty new thing called [Native File System API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/08/native-file-system) if you're using Chrome. But as I never tried it before, I can't tell if it'll work.